# How to set Excel margins with EPPlus

Tags: excel, epplus

I need to be able to set the margins (printer settings) of an Excel workbook programmatically.
I found this file:

[ExcelPrinterSettings.cs](https://github.com/ylatuya/EPPlus/blob/master/EPPlus/ExcelPrinterSettings.cs)

There is a class with following constructor:

```
ExcelPrinterSettings(XmlNamespaceManager ns,
    XmlNode topNode,ExcelWorksheet ws)
```

but I don't know what I should pass in for the first two parameters.
I already had code that makes a worksheet, so I can pass that in as 3rd parameter.

Many thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I use epplus with this code for set printer settings in target excel file:

```
ExcelWorksheet ew;
ew.PrinterSettings.TopMargin = tartetTopMarginValueInCm / 2.54M;
ew.PrinterSettings.RightMargin = targetRightMarginValueInCm / 2.54M;
...
ew.PrinterSettings.HeaderMargin = targetHeaderMarginInCm / 2.54M;
```

Don't forget convert cm to inch (if you want use cm, because all epplus printer settings values are in inch).

Screen with **Page setup** in Excel vs. **PrinterSettings** in Epplus:

[image: Page setup in excel vs. epplus settings]

Comment: Many thanks. I already found it out, due to code completion/Intellisense. And it indeed seems to work. I did not use ExcelPrinterSettings.cs at all.

Answer (score 3):

Same as Above with little adjustments (works 100%)

```
ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Demo");

ws.PrinterSettings.TopMargin =(decimal).5 / 2.54M; // narrow border
ws.PrinterSettings.RightMargin = (decimal).5 / 2.54M; //narrow border
```